# One-hot encode a column of integers into a NumPy matrix, including missing indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, one-hot-encoding

From the following NumPy array:

```py
[5, 2, 4, 6, 3]
```

I'd like to get to the following matrix:

```py
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

Using Pandas `get_dummies` appears very simple:

```py
pd.get_dummies(original_array).values
```

But it has one drawback, in that missing indices are not represented as columns (e.g. 0, 1 in this example) in the final matrix.

If we assume that the exact names/indices of the desired "columns" are known in advance (here, all integers from 0 to 6 included), what would be the most efficient way to get to the matrix shown above, starting from the initial array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a 2D NumPy array with value 1 at indices represented by values in 1D NumPy array (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327593/how-to-get-a-2d-numpy-array-with-value-1-at-indices-represented-by-values-in-1d)

Comment: @Ch3steR it does — feel free to refer to it. I didn’t find it because the title is not very searchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced indexing is your answer! Assuming you know your desired final shape (here, `(5, 7)`):

```py
In [5]: desired_shape = (5, 7)

In [6]: z = np.zeros(desired_shape, dtype="uint8")

In [5]: z
Out[5]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)

In [6]: idxs = [5, 2, 4, 6, 3]

In [7]: z[range(len(z)), idxs] = 1

In [8]: z
Out[8]:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a *zeros* matrix and then use advanced indexing to assign one to correct columns:

```
a = [5, 2, 4, 6, 3]

ohe = np.zeros((len(a), max(a) + 1), dtype=int)
ohe[np.arange(len(a)), a] = 1

ohe
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```